# Relative path for ipynb run within ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, path, jupyter

I'm working with multiple projects which need to be separated into their own directories. Each directory has a few .ipynb files which utilize relative paths to direct the scripts to various inputs from the .ipynb's location, since my team accesses these file through GITs which may be in different absolute paths on different coworker's devices.

This was all well and good until I started working on a script which pulls these other .ipynb files in via the %run command. When I run the functions defined in these files, they use my current working directory as the starting location for their own relative paths.

For example, I have lemon.ipynb in GIT/tools/lemons/functions/lemon.ipynb which uses relative path '..\inputs\lemonfactors.csv' to import GIT/tools/lemons/inputs/lemonfactors.csv.

If I create a new file in GIT/tools/master.ipynb and use %run to import the functions defined in the lemon.ipynb file, those functions will try the same relative path, but relative to my current location so it will look for GIT/inputs/lemonfactors.csv which doesn't exist.

How can I ensure in the lemon.ipynb file that it will always look relative to its own file location? `__file__` doesn't work in Jupyter, and all attempts to use variations on getcwd(),e tc. run into the same problem that the relative paths did.

Thanks for the insight.